# How to make the summ (total) with php if there is more than one price?

Tags: php

I'll make it simple, let's say i have a shopping cart, and three different prices:

1. $price
2. $specialprice
3. $salesprice

of course there are product quantities.

The first step of math is:

```
<?php

   $price_regular = $price * $quantity
   $price_special = $specialprice * $quantity
   $price_sales   = $salesprice * $quantity

?>
```

**So let me make a simple example, after adding 3 products in cart:**

1. Product A  - 30$ ($price)
2. Product B  - 25$ ($specialprice)      (old price was 30$)
3. Product C  - 22$ ($salesprice)        (old product was 35$)

The summ shoud be 77$.

**This is the result i want to get from my code.**

**But HOW?**

I tried doing smthing like:

```
<?php
    $totalprice = $totalprice + $price_regular; 
?>
```

but it only gives me the summ of REGULAR price. I need the code to calculate exactlly as in my simple example with product A - B - C

This is the real code from my file:

```
$totalprice = 0;
                $totalarticles = count($itemsonpage);
                for ($i=0;$i<=(count($itemsonpage) - 1);$i++){
                $productslist[$i]['id'] = $itemsonpage[$i]['productid'];
                $products->ShowByID($itemsonpage[$i]['productid']);
                $productslist[$i]['code'] = $products->code;
                $products->ShowLangDataByID($products->id,$chooselang);
                $productslist[$i]['name'] = $products->name;
                $productslist[$i]['quantity'] = $itemsonpage[$i]['quantity'];
                $productslist[$i]['price'] = $itemsonpage[$i]['price'];
                $productslist[$i]['specialprice'] = $products->specialprice;
                $productslist[$i]['salesprice'] = $products->salesprice;
                $productslist[$i]['allprice'] = $products->price * $productslist[$i]['quantity'];
                $productslist[$i]['allprice2'] = $products->specialprice * $productslist[$i]['quantity'];
                $productslist[$i]['allprice3'] = $products->salesprice * $productslist[$i]['quantity'];


                $totalprice = $totalprice + $productslist[$i]['allprice'];
```

Comment: there are large chunks of logic missing here, how to know which of the 3 price options to apply for a start. the pseudo code example is meaningless, how about some real code.

Comment: I am also not following - you can't add 3 numbers or something else is missing?

Comment: Why is it that the first product should apply with its regular price, and the second product with the special price, and the third product with the sales price? If you can explain this, you have your logic to decide which price to add. Additional questions: What if there are only two products in the basket, or four or more?

Comment: Yes you asked the right question... Therfore i am looking for a way to  find fisrt the right product price (regular or special or sale) then just add them

Comment: May be you just compare 3 prices (regular, special, sales) and choose the lowest for each product. It depend on the seller's rules, I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$totalprice += $price_regular; 
$totalprice += $price_special;     
$totalprice += $price_sales;   
echo $totalprice;
?>
```

Comment: Undefined var, $totalprice

Comment: Product A - 30$
product B - Salep price 22$, old price 30$

Comment: With your example it will do this

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you calculate it like this?

```
<?php
$totalprice = $price_sales + $price_special + $price_regular; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding just the `$price_regular` you are only getting that in `$totalprice`. You need to try something like this, adding up all the 3 prices,

```
 $totalprice = $price_regular + $price_special + $price_sales;
```

Comment: I did also this way, but it only calculates the price_regular

Comment: what values do you get, when you do a `print_r` on `$price_regular`, `$price_special`, `$price_sales`?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine in your cart there are several products, and you don't know how many. You should read up about [PHP arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) and about [PHP loops](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp).

Then, to use an array and a loop to carry out your sum, you would use an operation like this:

```
<?php
$totalprice = 0;

$prices=array(30,25,22);
foreach ($prices as $each)
  {
    $totalprice += ;
  }

echo $totalprice."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: i think i like your way i would add the real code in your answere so that you will se what i really have...

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you need to add 3 numbers, all the answers above tell you how to add 3 numbers.

I figure you actually asked the wrong questions so I will give you a wrong answer maybe it is what you want.

You have the following db structure
table product (id, name, price_sales, price_special, price_regular)

price_sales and price_special can be 0, that shows that that product is not on sale or on special.

TO get the total you have to perform a select on each product from the db based on the id and you get an object with the columns as properties. Your code should be something like this.

```
    $products = function_that_gets_the_products_from_the_db();
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $total_cart += $product->price_sales ? $product->price_sales : ($product->price_special ? $product->price_special : $product->price_regular)
    }
```

This code checks if the product is on sale, if it is then it uses that price, if it is not then it checks if it is on special, if it is then it uses that price otherwise it uses the normal price.